# Populate Local Branch Address in Footer

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'd like a Word document template that, when opened, requests office location name then enters the proper address and phone number for that location in the footer.

I thought to use a drop down list to select the location, I.E. Denver, LA, SF, NY etc. then have the code enter the address and phone number in the footer.

I can get the code to put an address or phone number in the footer but not stacked. The last one overwrites the first.

```vb
Sub FooterAddress()

 FooterAddress Macro

With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)

  .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Local Office City"
  .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "123 My Street | City, ST 12345-6789"
  .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Phone 800.123.4567"
 
End With

End Sub
```

I tried to use formatting codes for headers and footers to choose the font and center the text but just got errors.  Didn't try changing the color yet.

I can't get the dropdown to launch the script and I can't get the template to launch the dropdown on open either.

Comment: The way I approached putting local information into general templates was by use of a local global template that contained AutoText entries that were specific to the location (address, phone number, manager name) and using AutoText fields in the templates that would update when a new document was created.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub FooterAddress()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = _
  "Local Office City" & vbCr & _
  "123 My Street | City, ST 12345-6789" & vbCr & _
  "Phone 800.123.4567"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the footer, create *bookmarks* for each line (**Insert>Bookmark**). Then write to the bookmarks with:

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footer(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Bookmarks("Bookmarkname").Range.Text = "AddressText"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the footer up in the template and format it as you require so that you don't need to apply formatting in your code.

Place your cursor Where you want the office address to be and go to Insert | Quick Parts | Document Property | Company Address. Without changing the selection go to the Developer tab and click on Properties to display the Content Control Properties dialog. Click the box marked "Allow carriage returns", as shown below, and click OK.

[image]

Now move your cursor to where the phone number should be and from the same menu as before add Company Phone. You don't need to do anything else with this content control.

You can use the code below to set the values of the content controls.

```
Public Sub WriteOfficeAddress(ByVal officeAddress As String, ByVal officePhone As String)
  Dim cxpTarget                   As CustomXMLPart
  Dim strNamespace                As String

  strNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/coverPageProps"
  strNodeName = "/ns0:CoverPageProperties[1]/ns0:"
  Set cxpTarget = ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace(strNamespace).Item(1)
  cxpTarget.SelectSingleNode(strNodeName & "CompanyAddress").Text = officeAddress
  cxpTarget.SelectSingleNode(strNodeName & "CompanyPhone").Text = officePhone

End Sub
```

For your code to respond to a new document being created from your template you need to add code into the ThisDocument module. Use the drop downs at the top of the code window to create a Document New event, as shown below.

[image]